# Magento 2.3.4 multi-store customer session transfer

Tags: magento2, multistore, session, customer-session, subdomain

I have installed Fresh Magento 2.3.4, and set multiple store with websites on sub-domains.
I want customers to signin in one store and then automatically signedin on another store on sub-domain.
I have set cookie domain to like example.com (where sub-domain is sub.example.com). It isn't working. Plus also did set cookie-domain to ".example.com", it then makes customer and admin signin pages reload to again signin page. Anyone has idea about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working now. Just add "example.com" to cookie domain and leave cookie path empty.
Then clear Magento cache and browser cookies or try incognito mode. Working fine.